# Doors lock from fob, then unlock themselves

Tags: electrical, locks, door, jaguar, s-type

I have a 2002 S-Type Jaguar. When I hit the door lock button on the remote, they lock, then they all open back up in a few seconds. I can't keep them locked. What is causing this? Can anyone help me? I can hear it locking them all, then it beeps beeps and they unlock.

Comment: I wouldn't know the exact cause, but it would seem to me that the body control module thinks the doors should not be locked. Like a safety feature to ensure you don't lock yourself out of the car because you left the keys in the ignition.

Answer (score 6):

I've had central locking refusing to stay locked with several cars when any of the door sensors (or boot lid sensor, or even engine cover sensor) thinks its door is open - whether it's actually the case, or the sensor has jammed for some reason. This hypothesis can be checked by setting the interior lighting to the setting where it lights upon open doors. In most cases, opening and closing the culprit door/lid would solve the issue.

Comment: I will try this, thanks for getting back to me, this is a great site! sincerely, capt.j

Comment: I'm facing this issue ATM. Toggling the lights upon open doors is not practical. Is there any other workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen on my Nissan Altima when the mechanic left the key in the ignition while working on the car and reconnected the battery with the key in the ignition. This some how confused the car and it thought the key was still in the ignition even when it wasn't and was trying to keep me from locking myself out of the car. I disconnected the battery and let it sit for a while and then reconnected it. That seemed to reset things and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to move like two meters away from the car, it will lock.

When you are near the door, the module senses your keyfob and unlocks the door.

Comment: Yes it has worked by standing a couple of metres, well done you , I spent over an hour trying to find out what the problem was, and all I had to do was move away from my car .

Answer (score 1):

If its happening all the time, then it wouldn't be the doors/trunk/hood just being open. There are a couple of scenarios.

1. key fob is damaged,  button gets stuck,  or battery going out.
2. sensor on the doors/trunk/hood is going bad, and its sending back an open signal (prevents you from locking keys in your car).
3. electric lock module in doors is going bad, connector loose, or wires getting crimped.

My Honda does the same thing,  but mine is the lock module in the front passenger door.